# GRUB and os-prober unable to detect Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Allow me to give some context first.

So I was a goof and being a complete Ubuntu noob I deleted UEFI partition shortly after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I then booted back into Live CD to do a complete reinstall of Ubuntu, along with UEFI and boot disk repartitioning. I also then ran boot-repair to do Separate /boot/efi partition to sda6, which is where the EFI partition on my hard drive is located.

So boot-repair does its thing, but unable to detect the Windows OS installation in other partitions, thus unable to make EFI boot files for GRUB.

Please help! I really wanna go back to boot back to Windows.

For more info, I have tried boot-repair recommended install after Separate boot/efi partition, to no avail.

Link to boot-info: https://pastebin.com/niUX318E

Comment: The first thing you must do is to do a Windows boot repair. Boot with Windows 10 boot CD to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I have access to a Windows 10 boot CD because I installed Windows 10 through Windows 7 upgrade years ago.

Comment: Since UEFI can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12? Boot-Repair says "NTFS signature is missing." which often means chkdsk required but could be you left Windows fast start up or hibernation on. You may try f8 from direct boot of Windows, but usually need the Windows repair flash drive for Windows fixes.  Windows will turn fast start back on in back ground with updates, so always make sure it is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Be sure to always boot in UEFI boot mode as you also show grub in MBR for BIOS boot.

Comment: You can download a new Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft and burn it to a CD: https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: Okay, I'll try downloading the ISO.

Comment: And I'll attempt your fix as well oldfred, and get back to you asap.

Comment: So I tried direct boot through UEFI, and got messages indicating that Microsoft boot images were not found.

Comment: Booted Windows 10 install disk as well, ran startup repair and its not detecting the windows installation

Comment: Okay, looks like even windows boot cd isn't able to help. I'm going to make disk image of the windows partitions, delete those partitions, and do a clean install of windows again.

Comment: After you re-install Windows, the computer will boot straight to it. The easiest way to fix this problem is to use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows, which enables you to adjust the boot order.